# PHP & MySQL Archive based on School Year

Tags: php, mysql, date, archive

---

I need help creating an archive of posts based on school year. I've managed to create a normal archive with the help of this [**website**](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/238393/php-mysql-archive). I'm still a PHP newbie and feel like I'm missing something that might be obvious to the average back end developer.

Here is a tree view of what my archive currently looks like:

```
  2013

  April
      Post Title
  March
      Post Title
  February
      Post Title
      Post Title
      Post Title
  January
      Post Title
      Post Title
      Post Title

  2012

  December
      Post Title
      Post Title
      Post Title
  November
      Post Title
      Post Title
      Post Title
```

I can't help but feel like it's almost there, but I don't know how to get the site to know which date ranges to show. One thing I tried was adding this query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_date BETWEEN '2012-08' and '2013-07'") or die(mysql_error());
```

It worked and it's almost what I want... but I don't want to add queries for every school year til the end of time! There has got to be a better way to add these ranges than manually doing it for every year.

**Edit**: Here is my current code. It's giving me the error "Undefined index: hound_date"

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(   YEAR(hound_date-INTERVAL 7 MONTH),'-', 
                1+YEAR(hound_date-INTERVAL 7 MONTH))  AS 'academic year',
        COUNT(*) AS 'number of events'
   FROM hound
  GROUP BY CONCAT(   YEAR(hound_date-INTERVAL 7 MONTH),'-', 
                   1+YEAR(hound_date-INTERVAL 7 MONTH))") or die(mysql_error());




// An array to store the data in a more managable order.
$data = array();

// Add each entry to the $data array, sorted by Year and Month
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $hound_date=my_date($row['hound_date']);
    list($year,$month)=explode(" ", $hound_date);

    $data[$year][$month][] = $row;




    }   


    // Go through each Year and Month and print a list of entries, sorted by month.
    foreach($data as $_year => $_months)
        {
        echo '<hr/>';
        echo "<h2>{$_year}</h2>";
        foreach($_months as $_month => $_entries)
            {
            echo '<hr/>';
            echo "<h3>{$_month}</h3>";
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($_entries as $_entry)
                {
                echo '<li><a href="/?story='.$_entry["hound_id"].'">'.$_entry["hound_name"].'</a> </li>';

                }
            echo "</ul>";

            }
        }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are the limit date requested? Is there simply a page for each year that looks something like this?: `http://example.com/posts/2012/`

Comment: I don't currently have a start or end date in my code besides the query. How can I add a general start and end date? What I mean is if the school year starts in August and ends in May, how can I write the code to generate the start and end year for each school year?

Comment: I see, then you'll have to go with some [`date();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh I'm silly! Yes, I have a variable called table_date that posts the dates of every post.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is decide how your school years are defined.  They seem to be defined as follows:

1-August-2012 to 31-July-2013 is the 2012-2013 school year

That is, the academic year runs from the beginning of the seventh month.

If that's the case then you can use this MySQL expression to convert any particular date column to a text string like '2012-2013' denoting the academic year in which it occurs.

```
CONCAT(YEAR(datecol-INTERVAL 7 MONTH),'-', 1+YEAR(datecol-INTERVAL 7 MONTH))
```

For example, you could write a query like this to count the number of rows in each academic year.

```
 SELECT CONCAT(   YEAR(datecol-INTERVAL 7 MONTH),'-', 
                1+YEAR(datecol-INTERVAL 7 MONTH))  AS 'academic year',
        COUNT(*) AS 'number of events'
   FROM table
  GROUP BY CONCAT(   YEAR(datecol-INTERVAL 7 MONTH),'-', 
                   1+YEAR(datecol-INTERVAL 7 MONTH))
```

The point is, a little date arithmetic, in which you use `- INTERVAL 7 MONTH`, should convert calendar years to academic years quite nicely.

Comment: Thank you, let me give this a try and see how well it plays with my existing code :D

Comment: While this seems right (I know PHP but only some basic MySQL), I think it might be beyond the current understanding and goal of the OP.

Comment: I just edited my original post and provided my actual code. Ollie, I attempted to use your code, but it's giving me the error "Undefined index: hound_date". Do I need to have two queries to call the rest of the tables from the database?